# Volume subfolder and caching

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, lando

Docker on Mac suffers very poor performance. This is apparently caused by filesystem issues.

Thus I tried to cache some directories. I'm currently using `lando`, which is similar to docker-compose. By default it creates a volume, which map's the project root to /app.

What happens if I add more volumes which are subfolders?
Part of Folder Structure:

```
vendor/  
web/  
  core/  
..
```

E.g.:

```
volumes:  
    - ./vendor:/app/vendor:cached  
    - ./web/core:/app/web/core:cached
```

Do I end up with 1 uncached volume with everything and 2 cached volumes of subthemes? Or do the cached volumes "override" the uncached one?